# RegExp recursive

Tags: javascript, regex, recursion

I try to implement a recursion with a regexp to match all my items but that's not work.

Here is my regexp : ({)(\n([a-z-]*):([a-zA-Z0-9#.'"()]*)\;)*(\n})
And the string :

```
{
fill-color:#555;
fill-opacity:0.15;
fill-blend:'multiply';
}
{
stroke-color:#f90;
stroke-width:5pt;
stroke-opacity:0.2;
}
{
stroke-color:#f00;
stroke-width:0.5pt;
}
{
stroke-color:#f00;
}
]
```

And the link on reg101 to test : https://regex101.com/r/0dLyT4/2

With this regexp, I've got only the last iteration.

```
match1 > fill-blend:'multiply';
match2 > stroke-opacity:0.2;
match3 > stroke-width:0.5pt;
match4 > stroke-color:#f00;
```

What must I change to match :

```
match1 > fill-color:#555;
match2 > fill-opacity:0.15;
match3 > fill-blend:'multiply';
match4 > stroke-color:#f90;
match5 > stroke-width:5pt;
match6 > stroke-opacity:0.2;
match7 > stroke-color:#f00;
match8 > stroke-width:0.5pt;
match9 > stroke-color:#f00;
```

Thanks for your time !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following regex is matching your criteria.

```
(?m)^\s*\w+[^:]+:[^;\n]+;
```

Here is the link https://regex101.com/r/Sy7nmh/1

Comment: This is exactly what I need. Thanks @CoderX

Answer (score 1):

You could use a single capturing group and repeat a non capturing group `(?:...)*` inside it. Repeat the non capturing group 1+ times to prevent getting empty matches.

Using this pattern `[a-z\-]*):([a-zA-Z0-9#.'"()]*` with a `*` multiplier would also allow a single `:` to be matched.

Note that you don't have to escape the `\-` as it is the last char in the character class and the `\;` does not need escaping by itself.

```
\{\n((?:[a-z-]+:[a-zA-Z0-9#.'"()]+;\n)+)}
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/CmByoe/1)

If you also don't want to capture the ending newline, you could repeat the non capturing group 0+ times and match at least a single item where the last newline will be outside of the capturing group.

```
\{\n((?:[a-z-]*:[a-zA-Z0-9#.'"()]+;\n)*[a-z-]*:[a-zA-Z0-9#.'"()]+;)\n}
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Amtj2h/1)

Answer (score 0):

As regex101.com says:

> A repeated capturing group will only capture the last iteration. Put a
>   capturing group around the repeated group to capture all iterations or
>   use a non-capturing group instead if you're not interested in the data

Here is your regex fixed with a surrounding capture group: https://regex101.com/r/C7ANXp/1. What you need is in the group 2.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this regex. This will match all the CSS properties at `group1`.

```
{(\n+([a-z0-9#\.\-:'"]+;\n*)*)}
```

Here is [regex101 link](https://regex101.com/r/0dLyT4/3)